# how to pass "cipher-suite-blacklist" arguments to google-chrome(-stable) on linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome

Chrome is blocking access to pages with weak ephermeral Diffie-Hellman public keys.

Looking for a solution for Linux only, please don't bother telling me the solution for win/mac. I tried passing arguments to google-chrome and google-chrome-stable binaries, and it wasn't changing behavior.

```
google-chrome --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0088,0x0087,0x0039,0x0038,0x0044,0x0045,0x0066,0x0032,0x0033,0x0016,0x0013
```

trying to answer this same question on linux, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/966855/force-chrome-to-ignore-a-weak-ephemeral-diffie-hellman-public-key) "Force Chrome to Ignore a 'weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass that argument to Google Chrome on various operating systems by prepending --args before the arguments passed. Many Chrome/Chromium advanced flags will require the prepended value "--args" or they will not be recognized as options.

Keep in mind the actual paths may vary depending on operating system or customer installation location.

I have not been able to find any explanation as to why "--args" is required, but it is clearly used widely if you search for examples using various advanced flag options.

The "--args" flag is not needed for standard flags such as "-incognito" or "--new-window". As shown in this SU response: https://superuser.com/a/222078/239133

```
# Mac:
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app --args --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0088,0x0087,0x0039,0x0038,0x0044,0x0045,0x0066,0x0032,0x0033,0x0016,0x0013

# Win:
C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Google\Application\chrome.exe  --args --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0088,0x0087,0x0039,0x0038,0x0044,0x0045,0x0066,0x0032,0x0033,0x0016,0x0013

# Linux:
/usr/bin/google-chrome --args --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0088,0x0087,0x0039,0x0038,0x0044,0x0045,0x0066,0x0032,0x0033,0x0016,0x0013
```